# How to convert a Firestore Document to plain json and vice versa

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to fetch firestore document using Rest API and it is returning data in below format

```
{"fields":{"list1":{"arrayValue":{"values":[{"stringValue":"item1"},{"stringValue":"item2"}]}}}}
```

how can I convert the above Document to plain JavaScript object like below and convert it back to firestore document before making the update call

```
{"list1":["item1","item2"]}
```

Screenshot of my data from Firestore console
[image]

Edit: More info

json sample1 is returned by Firestore api  and has all datatype info

json sample2 is my actual data without type info.

My issue is firestore RestApi get call is returning the response in json sample1 format. I want to update some info in api response and send back updated values to firestore db. But due to all the type info in the response I'm not able to update the values where necessary. So I'm trying to find if there is a way to convert api response to json sample2.

API URL used : https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/projects/{project_id}/databases/{database_id}/documents/{document_path}

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do, and what the problem is. Both snippets you show are valid JSON as far as I can tell. Can you edit your question to show what code you've written, and what error you got, or where you got stuck?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen updated question with more info

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems with rest api only way is to write your own conversion. below code worked out for my requirement

```js
let jsonToDocument = function (value) {
    if (!isNaN(value)) {
        if (value.toString().indexOf('.') != -1)
            return { 'doubleValue': value };
        else
            return { 'integerValue': value };
    } else if (value === 'true' || value === 'false' || typeof value == 'boolean') {
        return { 'booleanValue': value };
    } else if (Date.parse(value)) {
        return { 'timestampValue': value };
    } else if (typeof value == 'string') {
        return { 'stringValue': value };
    } else if (value && value.constructor === Array) {
        return { 'arrayValue': { values: value.map(v => jsonToDocument(v)) } };
    } else if (typeof value === 'object') {
        let obj = {};
        for (let o in value) {
            obj[o] = jsonToDocument(value[o]);
        }
        return { 'mapValue': { fields: obj } };
    }

}
let documentToJson = function (fields) {
    let result = {};
    for (let f in fields) {
        let key = f, value = fields[f],
            isDocumentType = ['stringValue', 'booleanValue', 'doubleValue',
                'integerValue', 'timestampValue', 'mapValue', 'arrayValue'].find(t => t === key);
        if (isDocumentType) {
            let item = ['stringValue', 'booleanValue', 'doubleValue', 'integerValue', 'timestampValue']
                .find(t => t === key)
            if (item)
                return value;
            else if ('mapValue' == key)
                return documentToJson(value.fields || {});
            else if ('arrayValue' == key) {
                let list = value.values;
                return !!list ? list.map(l => documentToJson(l)) : [];
            }
        } else {
            result[key] = documentToJson(value)
        }
    }
    return result;
}
let documentData = { "list1": { "arrayValue": { "values": [{ "stringValue": "item1" }, { "stringValue": "item2" }] } } }
let jsonData = documentToJson(documentData);
let documentData1 = jsonToDocument(jsonData).mapValue.fields;
console.log(JSON.stringify(documentData));
console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonData));
console.log(JSON.stringify(documentData1));
```

Comment: Great snippet, thanks especially for posting both ways of conversion. Helped me a lot!

Answer (score 3):

I just want to suggest a minor change to @mahindar's answer to handle 'nullValue', as Firestore recently allowed saving null values. Below is the updated code

```js
let jsonToDocument = function (value) {
    if (!value) {
        return { 'nullValue': null };
    } else if (!isNaN(value)) {
        if (value.toString().indexOf('.') != -1)
            return { 'doubleValue': value };
        else
            return { 'integerValue': value };
    } else if (value === 'true' || value === 'false' || typeof value == 'boolean') {
        return { 'booleanValue': value };
    } else if (Date.parse(value)) {
        return { 'timestampValue': value };
    } else if (typeof value == 'string') {
        return { 'stringValue': value };
    } else if (value && value.constructor === Array) {
        return { 'arrayValue': { values: value.map(v => jsonToDocument(v)) } };
    } else if (typeof value === 'object') {
        let obj = {};
        for (let o in value) {
            obj[o] = jsonToDocument(value[o]);
        }
        return { 'mapValue': { fields: obj } };
    }

}
let documentToJson = function (fields) {
    let result = {};
    for (let f in fields) {
        let key = f, value = fields[f],
            isDocumentType = ['stringValue', 'booleanValue', 'doubleValue',
                'integerValue', 'timestampValue', 'mapValue', 'arrayValue', 'nullValue'].find(t => t === key);
        if (isDocumentType) {
            let item = ['stringValue', 'booleanValue', 'doubleValue', 'integerValue', 'timestampValue', 'nullValue']
                .find(t => t === key)
            if (item)
                return value;
            else if ('mapValue' == key)
                return documentToJson(value.fields || {});
            else if ('arrayValue' == key) {
                let list = value.values;
                return !!list ? list.map(l => documentToJson(l)) : [];
            }
        } else {
            result[key] = documentToJson(value)
        }
    }
    return result;
}
let documentData = { "list1": { "arrayValue": { "values": [{ "stringValue": "item1" }, { "stringValue": "item2" }] } }, "another_value": { "nullValue": null } }
let jsonData = documentToJson(documentData);
let documentData1 = jsonToDocument(jsonData).mapValue.fields;
console.log(JSON.stringify(documentData));
console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonData));
console.log(JSON.stringify(documentData1));
```

Comment: `!value` matches everything that evaluates to false, including empty strings, boolean false and much more. Checking via `value === null` would be better.

Answer (score 1):

How to convert a Firestore document into a normal JSON object:

```
function toValue(field) {
  return "integerValue" in field
    ? Number(field.integerValue)
    : "doubleValue" in field
    ? Number(field.doubleValue)
    : "arrayValue" in field
    ? field.arrayValue.values.map(toValue)
    : "mapValue" in field
    ? toJSON(field.mapValue)
    : Object.entries(field)[0][1];
}

function toJSON(doc) {
  return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(doc.fields ?? {}).map(([key, field]) => [key, toValue(field)])
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert this input:

```
{"fields":{"list1":{"arrayValue":{"values":[{"stringValue":"item1"},{"stringValue":"item2"}]}}}}
```

To this output:

```
{"list1":["item1","item2"]}
```

You can do:

```js
let input = {"fields":{"list1":{"arrayValue":{"values":[{"stringValue":"item1"},{"stringValue":"item2"}]}}}};

let expected = {"list1":["item1","item2"]};

let output = {};
Object.keys(input.fields).forEach((fieldName) => {
  let arrayValue = input.fields[fieldName].arrayValue;
  if (arrayValue) {
    output[fieldName] = arrayValue.values.map((value) => value.stringValue);
  }
});

console.log(output);
```

Comment: is it the only way? Because Json I have shared is sample one and the real document could have different structure with numbers, strings, arrays, dates and nested objects, arrays. I don't know if firestore api already has this ability to do this parsing at the api side itself

Comment: From a quick [search of the Firestore JavaScript SDK](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/search?q=arrayValue&unscoped_q=arrayValue) it seems that they're doing something similar. Unless you're using the Firestore JavaScript SDK, you'll have to write it yourself or start using a library that does this for you. But at that point, why not use the Firebase JavaScript SDK to begin with?